# Break a line after multiple matched words - python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a line of words:
`Dane osobowe po zmianie (dopisane): Surname1 Name1 (RYSZARD, EUGENIA) Zam. 99-100 Muczyn (Geod) 6A, Płeć: K, PESEL: 99945104321 Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16 0002.G56 Surname2 Name2 (ANDRZEJ, AGNIESZKA) Zam. 99-100 Muczyn (Geod) 4A, Płeć: K Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16 0001.G07 0001.G43 Surname1 Name1 Name2 (ANDRZEJ, AGNIESZKA) Zam. 99-100 MUCZYN (Geod) 4A, Płeć: M Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16`

I want to break into multiple lines in certain pattern:

`Dane osobowe po zmianie (dopisane): Surname1 Name1 (RYSZARD, EUGENIA) Zam. 99-100 Muczyn (Geod) 6A, Płeć: K, PESEL: 99945104321`

`Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16 0002.G56`

`Surname2 Name2 (ANDRZEJ, AGNIESZKA) Zam. 99-100 Muczyn (Geod) 4A, Płeć: K`

`Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16 0001.G07 0001.G43`

`Surname1 Name1 Name2 (ANDRZEJ, AGNIESZKA) Zam. 99-100 MUCZYN (Geod) 4A, Płeć: M`

`Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16`

I have a code:

`for i in range(0, len(data)):
    data[i] = data[i].replace(' Jednostki', '\nJednostki')`

in `data` I have single line as mentioned above. With this I managed to break it like that:

`Dane osobowe po zmianie (dopisane): Surname1 Name1 (RYSZARD, EUGENIA) Zam. 99-100 Muczyn (Geod) 6A, Płeć: K, PESEL: 99945104321`

`Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16 0002.G56 Surname2 Name2 (ANDRZEJ, AGNIESZKA) Zam. 99-100 Muczyn (Geod) 4A, Płeć: K`

`Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16 0001.G07 0001.G43 Surname1 Name1 Name2 (ANDRZEJ, AGNIESZKA) Zam. 99-100 MUCZYN (Geod) 4A, Płeć: M`

`Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16`

So, the problem is that I wan't it to break further after  `0001.G16 0002.G56` or `Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16 0001.G07 0001.G43`

There's probably regex needed but how do I deal with that number of `0001.G**` is changing.

Cheers!

Comment: Specific rules please.

Comment: I want line to split after `Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16 0001.G07 0001.G43` for example but also after `Jednostki Rejestrowe osoby (w gminie): 0001.G16` The number of `0001.G**` might change.

Comment: What Python version is it? If 3.5+, try `re.sub(r'(\.G\d+)\s*(?=(?:(?!\.G\d).)*?Jednostki\b)|(Jednostki)\b', '\\1\n\\2', data)` to add newlines, then split.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match `[0-9]{4}.G[0-9]{2}(?: [0-9]{4}.G[0-9]{2})*`

Replace with `\0\n`

https://regex101.com/r/5sfaeL/2

Both operations with a single regexp:

Match `([0-9]{4}.G[0-9]{2}(?: [0-9]{4}.G[0-9]{2})* |( )(?=Jednostki))`

https://regex101.com/r/5sfaeL/3

regex101 also provides an explanation of what's going on.